# Не полностью удаляется объект (Django Rest Framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Всем привет!
Есть несколько ViewSet'ов. Их объединяет один Serrializer и одна модель.
Каждый viewSet, по сути, является готовым линком с правильной выдачей (фильтрацией).

К примеру, два вьюсета - Favorites и Posts.
Если в Posts я применю на объект DELETE, то он удалится только из Posts, но в Favorites он останется. ОДНАКО, у каждого объекта есть поле URL, и допустим если в Posts объект удален, то в Favorites я его вижу и когда перехожу по по полю url, то в ответ получаю 404 not found.

Почему так происходит и как сделать так, чтобы если, к примеру я удаляю откуда либо, то удалится и в других вьюсетах.

Модель:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='name', db_index=True, max_length=64)
    city = models.CharField(verbose_name='city', db_index=True, max_length=64)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(default=next_month, blank=True, editable=False)
    description = models.CharField(verbose_name='description', db_index=True, max_length=64)
    isFan = models.BooleanField(null=True)
    main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_auth_dir_path, null=True, max_length=255)
    first_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_auth_dir_path, null=True, max_length=255)
    second_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_auth_dir_path, null=True, max_length=255)
```

ViewSet'ы:

```
class PostViewSet(LikedMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.is_actual().order_by('-created')
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, )
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filterset_fields = (...)


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)


class ClosedPostViewSet(LikedMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.is_not_actual().order_by('-end_time')

    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication,)
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = (...)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)


class SearchViewSet(LikedMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    pagination_class = None
    queryset = Post.objects.is_actual()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication, )
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, )
    filterset_fields = (...)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        result_list = list(queryset.values('city').annotate(count=Count('city')))
        return Response(result_list)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Скиньте код  с models.py

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, обновил

Comment: у вас только одна модель?  Пропустил этот момент. Тогда лучше добавьте viewsetы ващи

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, добавил вьюсеты. Да, модель используется одна.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, заметил такую особенность - во viewset'e, к примеру в ClosedPosts, в объекте есть поле URL, которое вообще ведет в другой вьюсет Posts